# bind() with arrow functions?

Tags: javascript

I found out that if I trying to bind an arrow function it's not working.

Working:

```
const person = {
name: 'itzik',
age: 21,
get: () => person.name+person.age
}
function logname () {console.log(this.get)}
const logPerson = logname.bind (person)
logPerson()
```

But if I change the function `logName` to an array function, like this:

```
const logName = () => console.log(this.get)
```

In this case, the `this` will reference to the window object.
Why is that?

Comment: When you say array function, I think you mean arrow function.

Comment: Since when were keywords case-insensitive?

Comment: yes, that's a 'gotcha' of using fat arrows. the are ways around it, and sometimes it even comes in pretty handy. check out this link: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881